# Chrome sometimes reloads image after jQuery .appendTo, recieves 304

Tags: image, google-chrome, reload

I'm building a slider. There is a set of slides, which I'm using as a content source and  this content is appended to a transition wrapper everytime the slide is changing. After the transition finishes, the transition wrapper is removed from DOM. When I add completely new content (image) to the slider and I open it in Chrome for the first time, this image is not, of course, in Chrome's cache. The problem shows when I append the transition wrapper (with this new image) into DOM. Chrome **sometimes (and sometimes not)** sends a request to get that image and recieves a 304 response. It makes this request even 3x for the same image. But it really happens only when the slider with the new images is loaded for the first time. After refresh, the Chrome gets those "new" images from its cache and the slider works perfectly. Other browsers are OK.

BTW: I also use imagesLoaded plugin, but image preloading doesn't seem to have any effect on this problem.

I know there are better approaches to create image slider - using images as background-image etc. But my content source => transition wrapper is the way I'm using to create responsive / not-only-image / CSS3 slider.

I'm going to release this plugin soon, so I would really like to solve this problem quickly.