# Chrome: Prevent image reload when rebuilding image elements

Tags: image, angularjs, google-chrome

Using AngularJS:

I'm displaying a list of images with ng-repeat. When I reset and rebuild the model (get new data from backend), I'm displaying the same images as before.

I understand these are new elements created by ng-repeat, but the image srcs are the same. Unlike IE or firefox, Chrome tries and gets a 403 for those same images and then renders them.

That causes a flicker. On IE and Firefox the images come from cache. No hit on the server to check for image changes. No flicker.

How can I prevent that? Should the images be served with some cache header? I tried loading the images to a dataurl, but then I hit the CORS problem, and would have to proxy those images on the backend to get them.

Possibly related: [Chrome sometimes reloads image after jQuery .appendTo, recieves 304](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086239/chrome-sometimes-reloads-image-after-jquery-appendto-recieves-304)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some fix would be related to preload the images in javascript and after that display them

```
function loadImages(arrayOfImgs) {
    var imageNumber=0;
    $(arrayOfImgs).each(function(){        
        (new Image()).src = this;
         if(arrayOfImgs.length == imageNumber) $scope.showImages = true;
         else imageNumber++;
    });
}

// Usage:
loadImages([
    'img1.jpg',
    'img2.jpg'
]);
```

if you are retriving images from backend use it at success promise

i hope it helps you

Check that example retrinving images from backend:

```
$scope.loading = true;
               getImages().then(function (response) {
                    var objects= response.results;

                    var listImages = [];

                    angular.forEach(objects, function (item) {
                        listImages.push(item.UrlImage);
                    });

                    function preload(arrayOfImages) {
                        var numImages = 0; 
                        $(arrayOfImages).each(function () {
                            var img = (new Image());
                            img.src = this;

                            $(img).load(function () {
                                numImages++;
                                if (numImages == arrayOfImages.length){
                                    $scope.loading = false;
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    preload(listImages);

                 });
```

Comment: Is '(new Image()).src = this' synchronous? Or I'm better off waiting for an "onload" for each image and decreasing a counter, and _then_ setting showImages to true?

Great example. I'll definitely use it almost as is. Will report back tomorrow. Thanks!